# Grouping based on time stamp in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table with two columns produced and timestamp. It records data for every minute and the produced says the number of boxes produced per minute. If I want to calculate the production every 5 mins,how can I do the grouping on timestamp column and get the sum. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your time column is a `TIMESTAMP` data type, you can use:

```sql
SELECT timestamp - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE * MOD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM timestamp), 5)
         AS five_minute_time_range,
       SUM(boxes_per_minute)
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       timestamp - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE * MOD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM timestamp), 5)
ORDER BY
       five_minute_time_range
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (timestamp, boxes_per_minute) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:00' + (LEVEL - 1) * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE,
       LEVEL
FROM   DUAL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 30;
```

Outputs:

> | FIVE_MINUTE_TIME_RANGE | SUM(BOXES_PER_MINUTE) |
> | --- | --- |
> | 01-JAN-21 00.00.00.000000000 | 15 |
> | 01-JAN-21 00.05.00.000000000 | 40 |
> | 01-JAN-21 00.10.00.000000000 | 65 |
> | 01-JAN-21 00.15.00.000000000 | 90 |
> | 01-JAN-21 00.20.00.000000000 | 115 |
> | 01-JAN-21 00.25.00.000000000 | 140 |

---

If it is a `DATE` column then you can use:

```sql
SELECT datetime - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE * MOD((datetime - TRUNC(datetime)) * 24 * 60, 5)
         AS five_minute_time_range,
       SUM(boxes_per_minute)
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       datetime - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE * MOD((datetime - TRUNC(datetime)) * 24 * 60, 5)
ORDER BY
       five_minute_time_range
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=710db8b7764314e850fcc905115fe500)*